# Flame Virus and Role of MD5 checksum in Microsoft upddate

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

Recently I heard that Flame used [MD5 checksum collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) to [tamper with Microsoft update](http://www.forbes.com/sites/richardstiennon/2012/06/14/flames-md5-collision-is-the-most-worrisome-security-discovery-of-2012/).

My question is where does the MD5 checksum come into play?

From [this source](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGYQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/4/a94af289-a798-4143-a3f8-77004f7c2fd3/Windows%2520Update%2520Explained.docx&ei=c4nlT4G-J4OurAfTu8CKCQ&usg=AFQjCNHeRlY5qoISxRJbfBxSq-_lEtbJaw&sig2=tTExlrAiFGkZRweUT9gDPw) on Microsoft website:

1. Windows Update uses the Secure Socket Layer (SSL) protocol to send and receive information.
2. Each update is individually signed using the Secure Hashing Algorithm (SHA-1).

So where is MD5 used, is it used for authenticating the update site?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15617/what-cryptographic-flaw-was-exploited-by-flame-to-get-its-code-signed-by-micros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of FLAME, MD5 hash collision was exploited to forge an intermediate certificate in the PKI rooted at Micosoft. The clients rely on such PKI to validate an update file really comes from Microsoft.

The certificate associated to the actual fake update file may have been signed using SHA-1 or any other strong hash algorithm. The problem is that an existing genuine intermediate PKI CA entity had its certificate signed with MD5. The attackers exploited the weakness of such algorithm to forge a second PKI CA certificate that they could use to further sign anything they liked.

SSL was not directly used in the attack (the Windows Update mechanism allows packages also from non-SSL sites).